# Как лучше вывести контент?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста алгоритм и инструменты.
Есть база, в которой находится контент. Выводится определенное количество контента - в зависимости от того, сколько помещается. Если пользователь скроллит вниз, то наличие контента на странице увеличивается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте из базы и выводите на странице только часть контента. Для этого в вашей базе данных наверняка есть специальные операторы, наподобие `limit` в MySQL или `ROWNUM` в Oracle.

При достижении скролл-позицией низа страницы запрашивайте следующий кусок ajax'ом, на стороне сервера точно так же читайте следующий кусок из базы.

Comment: ок. а как поступить со скроллингом? Как определить насколько вниз сдвинулся пользователь? И вообще как определить, что произошел скроллинг?

Comment: @Евгения: [`window.onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onscroll) или [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) на jQuery.

Comment: Ну и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303767/how-do-i-determine-height-and-scrolling-position-of-window-in-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464876/javascript-get-window-x-y-position-for-scroll

Comment: спасибо, попробую